# Invalid syntax when trying to use a string as an argument

Tags: python

This is my homework:

> Define a class called Lunch. It's `init()` method should have two
> arguments: `selfanf menu` where `menu` is a string. Add a method called
> `menu_price`. It will involve an if statement:

```
if "menu 1" print "Your choice:", menu, "Price 12.00", if "menu 2"
print "Your choice:", menu, "Price    13.40", else print "Error in
menu"
```

> To check if it works define: `Paul=Lunch("menu 1")` and call
> `Paul.menu_price().`

And this is my code:

```
class Lunch:
  def __init(selfanf, "menu".Where):
  
  def menu_price:

    if "menu 1":
      print("Your choice:", menu, "Price 12.00")

    if "menu 2":
      print("Your choice:", menu, "Price 13.40")

    else: 
      print("Error in menu.")

Paul = Lunch("menu 1")

paul.menu_price()
```

My problem is that I don't know how to include a string as an argument in **init**. I googled as much as I could and couldn't figure it out. Here is the error message:

> File "main.py", line 3
> def __init(selfanf, "menu".Where):
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The error occurred on this line: `def __init(selfanf, "menu".Where):` You say you can't figure out what's wrong with it, but I can't figure out what you expect it to mean or how you expect it to work.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel there are typos in the given homework instruction, see my answer below.

Comment: "Define a class called Lunch.Its init() method should have two arguments:selfanf menu.Where menu is a string." Are you sure you *read* this correctly? I think it probably was supposed to say: "Its `__init__()` method should have two arguments: `self` and `menu`, where `menu` is a string". What I mean is: `Where` has *nothing* to do with the name of the argument, it's part of the ordinary English text explaining to you what you're supposed to do.

Comment: When the assignment says "`menu` is a string", that doesn't mean "put `menu` in double quotes in your program", it means "when you call the function, you should pass a string to be used as the `menu` parameter".

Comment: If this assignment was handed to you on paper, could you show us a scan of the page? If it's online, could you show us the URL?

Comment: I think you need to scan the paper assignment.

Comment: "My problem is that I don't know how to include a string as an argument in init. I googled as much as I could and couldn't figure it out." Could you show some of the things you tried typing into Google?

Comment: Based on what I've seen so far, I recommend that you drop the course. Don't give up - just pick a different place to learn. This one clearly has failed to communicate anywhere near as much as you need to know, and the instructor apparently *doesn't even care enough about you as a student* to check the assignment specification for simply typos. The assignment is also terribly designed - you're being told exactly what to do half the time, while other things ("what should `__init__` *do with* its input?") are completely left out. You don't deserve to be treated like that.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm scared of the "w" on my transcript which is why I haven't dropped out. I will admit, he's not a very good teacher.

Comment: @anon_misid unrelated, but consider learning the material by yourself. The first ~10 chapters of "Automate the Boring Stufff with Python" (free online book) should be sufficient to learn syntax and basic procedural programming. The watch "Corey Schafer" on YouTube for Object Oriented programming (i.e. this exercise). This is the path I took, it is very common and reliable.

Comment: @anon_misid I agree with zrogravity, but only partially. I would say stay in the course, but then learn programming outside of the course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence of your instruction has several formatting issues and typos, and should read:

> Define a class called Lunch. Its `init()` method should have two arguments: `self` and `menu`, where menu is a string.

With this in mind, we can create the `init` signature as:

```
class Lunch:
    def __init__(self, menu):
        # construct new Lunch instance
```

Notes:

1. parameters defined by a function or method are identifiers, not data types, so they must conform to the usual identifier naming rules. Therefore a parameter like `"menu"` is not a valid identifier name. The word `menu` itself is a valid identifier, but `"menu"` enclosed in quotes is not. Rather, it is a string literal and should not be confused with a parameter name.
2. the statement `"menu".Where` is actually trying to access the `Where` property on the string literal "menu". Since string literals are of the string type, and there is no property `Where` defined on strings, this should fail.
3. some general advice, you are interpreting the instructions much too literally. For example, `if "menu 1" print "Your choice:", menu,` means `if (menu == 1): print ("Your choice:", menu, ...)`, not what you put which will always evaluate to true since the string literal "menu 1" is always True.
4. the `menu_price` method intends to check the `Lunch` instance's menu variable, so you would need to use `self.menu` in the `menu_price` method, and of course it must accept the implicit `self` as a parameter:

```
def menu_price(self):
    if (self.menu == 1):
        print("Your choice:", self.menu, "Price 12.00")
    elif (self.menu == 2):
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate both your answers and I admire the fact you were able to understand the instructions better than I could!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the error you are getting, let me give you a clue.

The error is in this line:

```py
print("Your choice:", menu, "Price 12.00")
```

Take a look at `menu`. Did you define `menu` inside the function `menu_price`? If not, then what do you have to add directly before it?

Answer (hover mouse over this to see):

> `print("Your choice:", self.menu, "Price 12.00")`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution to the instructions you have given, corrected as follows:

> Define a class called Lunch. Its `init()` method should have two arguments: `self` and `menu`. Where `menu` is a string. Add a method called `menu_price`. It will involve an `if` statement:
> if `menu` is 1, print `"Your choice:", menu, "Price 12.00"`, if `menu` is 2 `print "Your choice:", menu, "Price 13.40"`, else print `"Error in menu"`
> To check if it works define: `Paul=Lunch("menu 1")` and call Paul.menu_price()`.

```
class Lunch:
    def __init__(self, menu):
        self.menu = int(menu.strip()[-1]) # get last character of menu string after trimming the whitespace and cast it to int

    def menu_price(self):
        if (self.menu == 1):
            print("Your choice:", self.menu, "Price 12.00")
        elif (self.menu == 2):
            print("Your choice:", self.menu, "Price 13.40")
        else:
            print("Error in menu.")

Paul = Lunch("menu 1")

Paul.menu_price()
```

Comment: Why have you posted two answers?

Comment: Have you read both answers? If you have, and you believe that they should be merged into one they I will consider it. I feel like the two answers are unrelated.

Comment: There is a new error. It says "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    paul.menu_price()
  File "main.py", line 7, in menu_price
    print("Your choice:", menu, "Price 12.00")
NameError: name 'menu' is not defined" 

Which is confusing because menu is defined. It's 100% defined, so I don't understand why there's an error.

Comment: If I read both answers correctly, then the first answer is giving the OP indirect advice, and not direct code. This answer is giving the direct code, which I wouldn't do. How will the OP learn? Allow him to figure out the rest of the code, such as building the `Lunch` instance within the `init` function.

Comment: @10Rep I've learned because this person has provided an explanation. Thank you, I do understand where you are coming from :)

Comment: Now is your chance to learn the important skill of *debugging*. Start by questioning your assumptions. Why do you expect that `menu` is defined? Where are you expecting the definition to *come from*?

Comment: @anon_misid To answer your error, take a look at my answer.